# Insert a record in Sqlite database in Sencha touch (in MVC structure)

Tags: sqlite, cordova, extjs, model-view-controller, sencha-touch-2

I want to insert a record into the SQLite database, I am currently using the Sencha touch with Phonegap, The actual way should be it must be handled in the Model,
I am setting the values to the model in the controlled but I also wrote the functions for insert, update and delete in the controller (which is not correct as I want to follow the MVC structure and these code must possess in the model), But i dont know How to achieve this , I am using Phonegap (so cordova plugin for SQLite is used), I dont want to use the Sencha SQLite thing, Is this possible with using the Phonegap Sqlite plugin? (if anyone wants i will share the code I have used) but it is of no use as it is in the controller and achieved through cordova plugin (simple JavaScript)

Thank you,

regards,

Shrinivas Pai

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own proxy by extending Ext.data.Proxy which wraps the cordova plugin functionality. 
Then you can use such proxy in a store to handle the model records.